# Calling a function when populating a PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a working php code as below, that populates an array with data from a mysql database. It is used to produce a table that in return is used in another php file to generate a google chart. 
But I need to reformat the data in the 'Timestamp' field, using the function JSdate($in,$type). Being a noob when it comes to php, how do I do that? I guess it should be done in the section where you iterate through each record in the database, rahter than just writing 'Timestamp', it should say JSdate('Timestamp','datetime'), but I cant get it to work. Probably a simple question for someone with more php experience ;-)

```
function JSdate($in,$type){
    if($type=='date'){
        //Dates are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd'
        preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/', $in, $match);
    } elseif($type=='datetime'){
        //Datetimes are patterned 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'
        preg_match('/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/', $in, $match);
    }

    $year = (int) $match[1];
    $month = (int) $match[2] - 1; // Month conversion between indexes
    $day = (int) $match[3];

    if ($type=='date'){
        return "Date($year, $month, $day)";
    } elseif ($type=='datetime'){
        $hours = (int) $match[4];
        $minutes = (int) $match[5];
        $seconds = (int) $match[6];
        return "Date($year, $month, $day, $hours, $minutes, $seconds)";   
    }
}


try {
    $dbname = 'database'; //  Add your Database name here
    $username = 'XXXXXX'; //  Add your Username here
    $password = 'XXXXXXX'; //  Add your password here
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=XXXXXXXXX;dbname=$dbname", $username,$password);
    echo "Connected successfully";
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


// First section of code is for generating data for Google Charts.
try {
  $result = $conn->query('SELECT *
  FROM tempdata_ny
  WHERE Timestamp > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1000 HOUR)');


// Create the variables for the Google Chart and define as arrays   
  $rows = array();
  $table = array();

// Define the array labels
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'Datetime', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Temp1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Temp2', 'type' => 'number')
  );
// Iterate through each record in the MySQL DB to populate the array        
 foreach($result as $r) {
      $data = array();
      $data[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Timestamp']);
      $data[] = array('v' => (float) $r['Temp_Sens1']);
      $data[] = array('v' => (float) $r['Temp_Sens2']);
    //  print "<pre>";
     // print_r($data);
    // print_r($r);
    //  print "</pre>";
      // Insert data array into $rows
      $rows[] = array('c' => $data);
    }


    $table['rows'] = $rows;


} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: https://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$data[] = array('v' => (string) $r['Timestamp']);
```

For

```
$data[] = array('v' => (string) JSdate($r['Timestamp'],'datetime'));
```

Comment: thank you very much, that was as simple as I thought and hoped it would be!